# How to test data stored in cache or not?

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis

I am learning the caching concept, and I just know that caching is very useful to make our application's execution more faster.

I also know in case of web application hosted on iis we should follow [this](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching) steps.

I did follow this step on offline. I didn't get that caching has started or not because my execution speed is the same.

Comment: No question is stupid.....a newbie's question is a newbie's question......it is when you have not done any research and ask a simple question you get a down vote.....not for all newbie questions.....

Comment: Thanks i did Find On Internet But i did not find that i want because i did not figuring out that my configuration is taking effect or not.
sometimes some question is making no sense to others and they did not give answer or try to help but do the criticizing that is why i write the last statement